# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0' not found

Tags: java, maven

I have just started with java dev. I am given a task of doing object serialization of avro format. I have broken my head trying different methods. The different IDEs and different tools, none of which have I been able to use to solve the issue, moreover they have made everything more complex and frustrating. I tried following a tutorial which didnt use an IDE per say but that was also unsuccessful as the Serialize.java class wasnt compiling. I'm presently trying to achieve the task using maven plugins and dependencies. I have just made a new Maven project on Intellij. This is my pom.xml where I have pasted the dependencies and plugins for avro format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>avroTrial2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The second plugin shows an error, I have done the maven syncing on intellij and thats how the error from first plugin was rectified. Now the  error being shown is : "Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found". I need to deal with this error first before I can go and get stuck on some avro error after this.

Comment: Why do you _need_ the compiler plugin? It is included by default

Answer (score 1):

This might be the reason behind it. The configuration part in the maven compiler plugin section and the properties basically do the same thing. You have configured twice and with different versions. It should be either one of them and in general should match with the java version you are using (more details could be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

This is not matching

```
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

with

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and only use one of them.

Comment: I have made both as 1.8 but the error still persists. Intellij identifies errors on 2 lines the groupId and artifactId of the second plugin. Both have same error which is "Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found". I have invalidated and restarted and synced with maven also.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered same problem so what I did to resolve it is:

1. Navigated to File->Settings in IntelliJ
2. Select `Plugin` from left bar and then I unchecked `Maven plugin`
3. Restarted the IDE
4. Again clicked on `Plugin` and checked `Maven`
5. Restarted the IDE